# How many n-digit numbers can we generate when each digit can be repeated max k times?

Tags: statistics

In case each digit can be repeated 2 times, I concluded that the amount of posibilities of numbers with

3 digits: 1000 digits - [000, 111, ... 999] 10 = 990 possibilities

4 digits: 10 * 990 - [0001, 0010, 0100, ..., 999n, 99n9, 9n99] 10 * 3 * 9 = 9,630

5 digits: 10 * 9630 - [000nm, 00n0m, 0n00m, 00nm0, 0n0m0, 0nm00] 10 * 6 * 9 * 9 = 91,440

6 digits: 10 * 91440 - 10 * 10 * 9 * 9 * 9

So, for n digits, it adds
$$
 10 * (the.amount.of.n-1.posibilities) - \sum_{i=n-2}^0 i * 9^{(n-2)}
$$

In case each digit can be repeated 3 times, I concluded that the amount of posibilities of numbers with

4 digits: 4 digit: 10000 - [0000, 1111, ..., 9999] 10 = 9,990

5 digits: 10 * 9990 - [0000n, 000n0, 00n00, 0n000] 10 * 4 * 9 = 99,540

6 digits: 10 * 99540 - 10 * 10 * 9 * 9 = 987,300

7 digits: 10 * 987300 - 10 * 20 * 9 * 9 * 9 = 9,727,200

I don't see the steps 1,4,10,20 are related.

And how would you write it for an n-digit numbere where each digit can be repeated maximum k times?

Answer (score 1):

A partial solution can be given using exponential generating functions. We are trying to count the partitions of $n$ digits into 10 collections such that each collection has at most k elements. The number of ways of doing this is $n!$ times the $n$-th coefficient in the polynomial expansion of
$$
(1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+...+\frac{x^{k}}{k!})^{10}.
$$